# Mongodb tutorial not sorting field {h}

Tags: mongodb

I just was playing with simple mongodb tutorial and when I try sort it doesn't seem to be working:

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
  { item: "journal", qty: 25, tags: ["blank", "red"], size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" } },
  { item: "mat", qty: 85, tags: ["gray"], size: { h: 27.9, w: 35.5, uom: "cm" } },
  { item: "mousepad", qty: 25, tags: ["gel", "blue"], size: { h: 19, w: 22.85, uom: "cm" } }
])
```

and then

```
> db.inventory.find().sort({h:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba02d6cc29157a810f9478b"), "item" : "journal", "qty" : 25, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ], "size" : { "h" : 14, "w" : 21, "uom" : "cm" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba02d6cc29157a810f9478c"), "item" : "mat", "qty" : 85, "tags" : [ "gray" ], "size" : { "h" : 27.9, "w" : 35.5, "uom" : "cm" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba02d6cc29157a810f9478d"), "item" : "mousepad", "qty" : 25, "tags" : [ "gel", "blue" ], "size" : { "h" : 19, "w" :  22.85, "uom" : "cm" } }
```

And so the "h" is returned as 14, 27.9, 19 which is not sorted. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort is working, just now how you would expect. The documents do not contain a top-level field `h` so all of the documents are sorted by `null`.

Instead, you will need to sort on `size.h` using [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). For example:

```
db.inventory.find().sort({ "size.h" : 1 } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba03209ebb1a32e62853cdf"), "item" : "journal", "qty" : 25, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ], "size" : { "h" : 14, "w" : 21, "uom" : "cm" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba03209ebb1a32e62853ce1"), "item" : "mousepad", "qty" : 25, "tags" : [ "gel", "blue" ], "size" : { "h" : 19, "w" : 22.85, "uom" : "cm" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba03209ebb1a32e62853ce0"), "item" : "mat", "qty" : 85, "tags" : [ "gray" ], "size" : { "h" : 27.9, "w" : 35.5, "uom" : "cm" } }
```

Comment: I tried that but without the quotes around the `"size.h"`. Thanks.